# Representer theorem - dot product of 2 summations

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, riesz-representation-theorem, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

The Representer theorem on the reproducing kernel Hilbert space has the form
\begin{align*}
\langle K(\cdot, x_i), f\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} = f(x_i)
\end{align*}
where $K$ is a reproducing kernel with eigen-expansion
\begin{align*}
K(x, y)= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lambda_i \phi_i(x) \cdot \phi_i(y)
\end{align*}
$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i \phi_i(x)$ is an element in the reproducing kernel Hilbert space. $c_i$ is some real coefficient.

[image]

The last line in the above attached image shows the Representer property. I am not sure about how the 2nd equation is justified. It will be great if someone can show how the dot product is expanded, and why there is $\lambda_i$ on the denominator. Thanks in advance!